# Clicking on button in Selenium Chrome Headless mode does not work

Tags: selenium-webdriver, button, selenium-chromedriver, headless, locate

I have a very annoying problem. I actually have found many people with this problem online and various solutions, but none of them work for me.

My code looks like the following, extract of the entire code:

```
for website in websites:
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1500,900");


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Use specific URL from Container
    driver.get(website["url"])


    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CollectorsClub"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/button[2]')))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Which basically opens a website, and then clicks on a specific button on the website. The code works smotth & perfectly if i remove the headless part and the browser manually opens, however with headless I get the following Timeout error: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:

I have also tried clicking the button like this, same error/result:

```
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CollectorsClub"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/button[2]')))

# Click the button
button.click()
```

As you can see, I have tried common solutions like setting a window size, I tried different ways of locating the button etc. etc., but it simply does not work.

I would greatly appreciate any inputs.

All the best
alex

Comment: Classic, have been working for 3 hours on this, the second I post it online I find the solution myself. Solution: website seems to block Headless requests.